# How the following program will work?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, comparator

I'm trying to sort the number 56,67,94,10 by using its second decimal place. Actually I am not getting what that returning 1 or -1 will do.

```
Collections.sort(arr, new Comparator<Integer>() {
        public int compare(Integer t1, Integer t2) {
            //System.out.print(" "+t1+" "+t2);
            if (t1 % 10 > t2 % 10) {
                return 1;
            }
            return -1;
        }
    });
```

Comment: What are your doubts?

Comment: Are you asking about the modules operator `%`? Or about what a `Comparator` is? Or something else? Please clarify.

Comment: @NiVeR actually I am not getting what that returning 1 or -1 will do

Comment: @PratikKulkar returning 1 means that t1 "should come after" t2; returning -1 means that t1 "should come before" t2

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks but would you please elaborate

Comment: @PratikKulkar what is unclear?

Comment: @AndyTurner Consider a scenario, function for swapping two numbers which returns true if numbers has to swapped or else false. So, returning 1 means true and returning -1 means false. Is it right or not?

Comment: @PratikKulkar you are just making up something else entirely, and trying to map it onto the contract of a Comparator. Comparators are very simple: if `compare(t1, t2)` returns -1 (or any negative number), then `t1 < t2`; if it returns 1 (or any positive number) then `t1 > t2`; otherwise (meaning it returned zero) `t1 == t2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return zero when that digit is equal.

The easiest way to do that is to replace the body of the comparator with:

```
return Integer.compare(t1 % 10, t2 % 10);
```

Or, easier:

```
Collections.sort(arr, Comparator.comparing(t -> t % 10));
```